# Battery reports it's fine, but notebook won't boot /wo AC plugged in

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hardware-failure, battery, acer-aspire

I am running Acer Aspire Timeline Ultra [M5-581TG](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-Timeline-Ultra-M5-581TG-Ultrabook.86415.0.html). I opened it up to clean (as I've done twice before), assembled it back and now observe weird behaviour: the laptop won't react to the power button unless it's plugged in. If I plug the laptop in, power it on and then plug it out, the laptop will power off.

However, the battery says it's fine. Here are the diagnostics:

```
all3fox@tardis ~ % acpi -V
Battery 0: Full, 100%
Battery 0: design capacity 4391 mAh, last full capacity 3233 mAh = 73%
Adapter 0: on-line

all3fox@tardis ~ % upower --dump
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
native-path:          AC0
power supply:         yes
updated:              Thu 19 Jun 2014 04:45:00 PM MSK (1283 seconds ago)
has history:          no
has statistics:       no
line-power
warning-level:       none
online:              yes
icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
native-path:          BAT0
vendor:               OEM
model:                AP12A3i
power supply:         yes
updated:              Thu 19 Jun 2014 05:05:00 PM MSK (83 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
present:             yes
rechargeable:        yes
state:               fully-charged
warning-level:       none
energy:              40.502 Wh
energy-empty:        0 Wh
energy-full:         40.502 Wh
energy-full-design:  55 Wh
energy-rate:         0 W
voltage:             12.525 V
percentage:          100%
capacity:            73.64%
technology:          lithium-ion
icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried to 'resit' the batter (pull it out, put it back in, etc.)?

Comment: Have you also tried to fully discharge the battery then charge it again?  Your battery is getting old "last full capacity ..."

Comment: @CharlesH I have tried resetting the battery after your suggestion but nothing has changed... I used a paperclip and followed the manual for my laptop to simulate battery extraction (done via a special hole at the back).

Comment: @Ramhound I can't run on battery -- the moment I unplug from AC, the laptop turns off. I suspect, I can't discharge it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fantastic! Turns out, the battery has to be *grounded* to the chassis, otherwise it'll refuse to operate. It was precisely my case: I ruptured some foil which touched one of the chassis screws around the battery. I replaced the foil and now it works!

To be brutally honest, I did not come up with that myself, a similar thing is described [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1702496/acer-aspire-581t-6405-battery-detected.html) about a similar laptop model (though in the case of my model, the screws' position is different):

> I have been working on this model laptop for a friend of mine and after working on it, it would not see the battery. Working on computers for a living, this bothered me. After trying all of the proposed fixes, nothing worked. Alas, I had given up and decided to button the laptop back up. This is when I found the solution. It turns out that the battery HAS TO BE GROUNDED to the case in order to operate. It does this through a case screw. The particular case screw it uses is about 1.5 inches above the power indicator LED. If you press in that general area with the laptop plugged in, you will see it start to charge. In order to solve this issue permanently, make sure that the screw in this mounting hole in in tight. This has frustrated me to no end, but I am happy to finally have a solution.

I might return here with a detailed blog post with photos because it's a very subtle matter!